# Select Anonymous type with Dynamic Expression API

Tags: c#, dynamic, linq-to-entities, expression

I'm using Dynamic Expression API (`System.Linq.Dynamic`) with LINQ to Entities.  My LINQ query is below.

```
var query = this.db.Products.AsQueryable()
           .Where(strCondition)
           .OrderBy("ProductNumber")
           .Select("new(ProductNumber, ProductDescription, ProductCategory.Name)");
```

Now that I have the "query", I don't know how to get the value of each of the field.

```
string strTemp;
foreach (var item in query)
{
    strTemp = item.?
}
```

It's anonymous type so I can't really use strongly type to get the value.  What can I do?  The reason I select to get anonymous type fields is because I need to get ProductCategory.Name field into the result.  Is there a better way to get ProductCategory.Name in the result with Dynamic Expression API?  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deal with it is to declare your loop variable to be `dynamic` since you don't have any static type information (the inferred static type is `object` but it is an instance of a `DynamicClass`).

```
foreach (dynamic item in query)
{
    string ProductNumber      = item.ProductNumber;
    string ProductDescription = item.ProductDescription;
    string Name               = item.Name;
}
```

Otherwise you can use reflection manually.

```
// static (extension) method to read the property
public static T GetProperty<T>(this DynamicClass self, string propertyName)
{
    var type = self.GetType();
    var propInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    return (T)propInfo.GetValue(self, null);        
}

// usage:
foreach (DynamicClass item in query)
{
    // using as an extension method
    string ProductNumber      = item.GetProperty<string>("ProductNumber");
    // or as a static method
    string ProductDescription = GetProperty<string>(item, "ProductDescription");
    string Name               = item.GetProperty<string>("Name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the property name you've used to create your anonymous object.
VS intellisense should pick them up.

```
string strTemp;
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            strTemp = item.ProductItem;
        }
```

You can specify your own property names as well:

```
.Select("new(ProductNumber as Number, ProductDescription as Description, ProductCategory.Name as Name)")
```

Comment: The problem is VS intellisense did not pick it up.  I assumed it because the query is using Dynamic Expression API which uses a string value.  Any clue?

Comment: @Seecott - You're right. VS won't pick them up. Take a look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I have looked at it before. No answer there.  Does anyone know how or has a sample code to get the item properties?