# How to access columns from an IQueryable when dynamically constructed?

Tags: dynamic, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I am using the System.Linq.Data library provided here - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

I have the following query which works great and returns an Iqueryable

```
IQueryable customer =
                ctx.Customers.Where(cust => true).Select("new("Name,Address")");
```

However, how do I access these returned columns? I cannot access them using a lambda expression as follows:

var test = customer.Where(cust=>cust.Name == "Mike").First();

"cust.Name" in the above case cannot be resolved. It does not exist in the list of methods/properties for "cust".

Am i assuming something wrong here. I understand that I am working with an anonymous type. Do I have to create a DTO in this case?

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050458/select-anonymous-type-with-dynamic-expression-api).

Comment: The sample there works for an explicit cast. However in my case I cannot cast "cust" to "DynamicClass" explicitly as lambda expressions don't support that. So i couldn't do something like this from the link you gave me: var test = customer.Where((DynamicClass)cust=>cust.Name == "Mike").First(); Also, I cannot use the first solution used which is the "dynamic" keyword because I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: Well, once you do a projection using a dynamic query, you can no longer use lambdas.  You must stick with dynamic expressions.  `var test = customer.Where("Name = \"Mike\"").First();`  Then when you get your test object, you can apply the steps in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

For any IQueryable you have property called ElementType.
You can use it to get the properties as explained below

```
IQueryable query = from t in db.Cities
               selec new 
               {
                  Id = t.Id,
                  CityName = t.Name
               };

if(query!=null)
{
    Type elementType = query.ElementType;
    foreach(PropertyInfo pi in elementType.GetProperties())
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try foreach loop:

```
var a = _context.SENDERS.Select(x=>new { Address=x.ADDRESS, Company=x.COMPANY });
foreach(var obj in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Address);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Company);
}
```